# Parsing Data Output in Python

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance

So I have this code:

```
si.get_stats("aapl")
```

which returns this junk:

```
0                          Market Cap (intraday) 5       877.04B
1                               Enterprise Value 3       966.56B
2                                     Trailing P/E         15.52
3                                    Forward P/E 1         12.46
4                      PEG Ratio (5 yr expected) 1          1.03
5                                Price/Sales (ttm)          3.30
6                                 Price/Book (mrq)          8.20
7                       Enterprise Value/Revenue 3          3.64
8                        Enterprise Value/EBITDA 6         11.82
9                                 Fiscal Year Ends  Sep 29, 2018
10                       Most Recent Quarter (mrq)  Sep 29, 2018
11                                   Profit Margin        22.41%
12                          Operating Margin (ttm)        26.69%
13                          Return on Assets (ttm)        11.96%
14                          Return on Equity (ttm)        49.36%
15                                   Revenue (ttm)       265.59B
16                         Revenue Per Share (ttm)         53.60
17                  Quarterly Revenue Growth (yoy)        19.60%
18                              Gross Profit (ttm)       101.84B
19                                          EBITDA         81.8B
20                  Net Income Avi to Common (ttm)        59.53B
21                               Diluted EPS (ttm)         11.91
22                 Quarterly Earnings Growth (yoy)        31.80%
23                                Total Cash (mrq)         66.3B
24                      Total Cash Per Share (mrq)         13.97
25                                Total Debt (mrq)       114.48B
26                         Total Debt/Equity (mrq)        106.85
27                             Current Ratio (mrq)          1.12
28                      Book Value Per Share (mrq)         22.53
29                       Operating Cash Flow (ttm)        77.43B
30                    Levered Free Cash Flow (ttm)        48.42B
31                               Beta (3Y Monthly)          1.21
32                                52-Week Change 3         5.27%
33                         S&P500 52-Week Change 3         4.97%
34                                  52 Week High 3        233.47
35                                   52 Week Low 3        150.24
36                         50-Day Moving Average 3        201.02
37                        200-Day Moving Average 3        203.28
38                             Avg Vol (3 month) 3         38.6M
39                              Avg Vol (10 day) 3        42.36M
40                            Shares Outstanding 5         4.75B
41                                           Float         4.62B
42                            % Held by Insiders 1         0.07%
43                        % Held by Institutions 1        61.16%
44                   Shares Short (Oct 31, 2018) 4        36.47M
45                    Short Ratio (Oct 31, 2018) 4          1.06
46               Short % of Float (Oct 31, 2018) 4         0.72%
47  Short % of Shares Outstanding (Oct 31, 2018) 4         0.77%
48       Shares Short (prior month Sep 28, 2018) 4         40.2M
49                  Forward Annual Dividend Rate 4          2.92
50                 Forward Annual Dividend Yield 4         1.51%
51                 Trailing Annual Dividend Rate 3          2.72
52                Trailing Annual Dividend Yield 3         1.52%
53                 5 Year Average Dividend Yield 4          1.73
54                                  Payout Ratio 4        22.84%
55                                 Dividend Date 3  Nov 15, 2018
56                              Ex-Dividend Date 4   Nov 8, 2018
57               Last Split Factor (new per old) 2           1/7
58                               Last Split Date 3   Jun 9, 2014
```

This is a third party function, scraping data off of Yahoo Finance. I need something like this

```
def func( si.get_stats("aapl") ):
     **magic**
     return Beta (3Y Monthly)
```

Specifically, I want it to return the number assocaited with Beta, not the actual text.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the function call returns a single string or list of strings for each line in the table and is not writing to the stdout.

To get the value associated with Beta (3Y Monthly) or any of the other parameter names:

1) If the return is a single string with formatting to print as the table above it should have \n at the end of each line. So you can split this string to a list then iterate over to find the parameter name and split again to fetch the numeric associated with it

```
# Split the single formatted string to a list of elements, each element
# is one line in the table
str_lst = si.get_stats("aapl").split('\n')
for line in str_lst:
    # change Beta (3Y Monthly) to any other parameter required.
    if 'Beta (3Y Monthly)' in line:
        # split this line with the default split value of white space
        # this should provide a list of elements split at each white space.
        # eg : ['31', 'Beta', '(3Y', 'Monthly)', '1.21'], the numeric value is the
        # last element. Strip to remove trailing space/newline.
        num_value_asStr = line.split()[-1].strip()
return num_value_asStr
```

2) If it already a list that is returned then just iterate over the list items and use the if condition as above and split the required list element to get the numeric value associated with the parameter.

```
str_lst = si.get_stats("aapl")
for line in str_lst:
    # change Beta (3Y Monthly) to any other parameter required.
    if 'Beta (3Y Monthly)' in line:
        # split this line with the default split value of white space
        # this should provide a list of elements split at each white space.
        # eg : ['31', 'Beta', '(3Y', 'Monthly)', '1.21'], the numeric value is the
        # last element. Strip to remove trailing space/newline.
        num_value_asStr = line.split()[-1].strip()
return num_value_asStr
```